# Can we see the templates instantiated by the C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-flags

Is there a way to see the compiler-instantiated code for a function template or a class template in C++?

Assume I have the following piece of code:

```cpp
template <class T> T add(T a, T b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

When I call:

```cpp
add<int>(10, 2);
```

... I would like to see the function that the compiler creates for the `int` template specialization.

I am using g++, VC++, and need to know the compiler options to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to see the function in C++ or in assembly? If in assembly, use `g++ -S`.

Comment: A closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4332286/57428

Comment: [c++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/) is what you want

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can definitely see the assembly code generated by the g++ using the "-S" option.

I don't think it is possible to display the "C++" equivalent template code - but I would still want a g++ developer to chime in why - I don't know the architecture of gcc.

When using assembly, you can review the resulting code looking for what resembles your function. As a result of running gcc -S -O1 {yourcode.cpp}, I got this (AMD64, gcc 4.4.4)

```
_Z3addIiET_S0_S0_:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    leal    (%rsi,%rdi), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Which really is just an int addition (leal).

Now, how to decode the c++ name mangler? there is a utility called c++filt, you paste the canonical (C-equivalent) name and you get the demangled c++ equivalent

```
qdot@nightfly /dev/shm $ c++filt 
_Z3addIiET_S0_S0_ 
int add<int>(int, int)
```

Comment: If people were allowed to see the generated template code, it would probably be too much to read anyway... in case of the STL

Comment: Well, people are allowed to see the generated assembly, it is quite a bit already, however, sometimes it is just what you need to gain valuable insight..

Comment: @qdot it is completely different to see the assembly and the c++ generated code. Sometimes you want to generate the hierarchy of the classes by using the TypeLists then you probably will need to see the results as a c++ code just to be sure in your hierarchy. Assembly doesn't help at all in this case.

Answer (score 100):

Clang (https://clang.llvm.org/) can pretty-print AST of instantiated template:

For your example:

*test.cpp*

```
template < class T> T add(T a, T b){
    return a+b;
}

void tmp() {
    add<int>(10,2); 
}
```

Command to pretty-print AST:

```
$ clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only test.cpp
```

Clang-5.0/Clang 14.0 output:

```
template <class T> T add(T a, T b) {
    return a + b;
}
template<> int add<int>(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
void tmp() {
    add<int>(10, 2);
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the best answer the OP is looking for (when compared with the other alternatives).

Answer (score 40):

If you want to see the assembly output, use this:

```
g++ -S file.cpp
```

If you want to see some (pseudo) C++ code that GCC generates, you can use this:

```
g++ -fdump-tree-original file.cpp
```

For your `add` function, this will output something like

```
;; Function T add(const T&, const T&) [with T = int] (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original

return <retval> = (int) *l + (int) *r;
```

(I passed the parameters by reference to make the output a little more interesting)

Comment: `g++ -fdump-tree-gimple file.cpp` will generate a more human readable format.

Answer (score 27):

Now there is an on-line tool which does this for you: https://cppinsights.io/ For example, this code

```
template<class X, class Y> auto add(X x, Y y) {
  return x + y;
}

int main()
{
  return add(10, 2.5);
}
```

Is translated to

```
template<class X, class Y> auto add(X x, Y y) {
  return x + y;
}

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:9 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
double add<int, double>(int x, double y)
{
  return static_cast<double>(x) + y;
}
#endif


int main()
{
  return static_cast<int>(add(10, 2.5));
}
```

https://cppinsights.io/s/0b914fd3

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. What a great find! In [the somewhat well-hidden About page](https://cppinsights.io/about.html), the author explains that C++ Insights is based on Clang but does a lot of its own work to produce more thorough and ideally C++-compilable 'intermediate' code than pretty-printed AST as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46573566/2757035) would get. It also produces 'raw' versions of things like range-based `for` loops, too. Very exciting!

Comment: @underscore_d yes, I also think it is a fantastic tool, which can be extremely helpful in some cases. As for accepted answer - yeah, it would be nice for visibility, as while people can debate pretty-print AST, I am 100% sure it is better than currently accepted answer of ASM.

Answer (score 3):

When the optimizer has done its deeds, you most likely have nothing left that looks like a function call. In your specific example, you'll definitely end up with an inlined addition, at worse. Other than that, you can always emit the generated assembler in a separate file during compilation, and there lies your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to inspect the generated assembly. You can get an assembly source by using -S flag for g++.

Answer (score 2):

I think [c++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for the equivalent C++ code then no. The compiler never generates it. It's much faster for the compiler to generate it's intermediate representation straight off than to generate c++ first.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, however for modern g++ you can use:

```
g++ -fdump-tree-*switch* -o array_size array_size.cpp
```

for *switch* use all to see all the types that can be used, you'll get about 32 files some are really big.  You can use the last component of the file name as the *switch* to get just that file such as `-fdump-tree-gimple`.

This code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t ARRAYSIZET(T (&a)[N])
{
    return N;
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::cout << ARRAYSIZET(a) << std::endl;
}
```

Turns into:
g++ -fdump-tree-gimple -o array_size array_size.cpp

```
int main (int argc, char * * argv)
{
  int D.53868;

  {
    int a[6];
    try
      {
        a[0] = 1;
        a[1] = 2;
        a[2] = 3;
        a[3] = 4;
        a[4] = 5;
        a[5] = 6;
        _1 = std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<< (&cout, 6);
        std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<< (_1, endl);
        _2 = ARRAYSIZET<int, 6> (&a);
        _3 = std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<< (&cout, _2);
        std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<< (_3, endl);
      }
    finally
      {
        a = {CLOBBER(eol)};
      }
  }
  D.53868 = 0;
  return D.53868;
}

size_t ARRAYSIZET<int, 6> (int[6] & a)
{
  size_t D.53874;

  D.53874 = 6;
  return D.53874;
}
```

man g++ and search for "dump".