# Explicit instantiation across multiple libraries

Tags: c++, templates, linker, explicit-instantiation

If I have some header with a template implementation:

```
#ifndef FOOHEADER_HPP
#define FOOHEADER_HPP
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
void FooFun(){}
};
#endif
```

And two `.cpp`-files which provides explicit instantiations of this declaration:

FloatFoo.cpp:

```
#include "FooHeader.hpp"
template struct Foo<float>;
```

IntFoo.cpp:

```
#include "FooHeader.hpp"
template struct Foo<int>;
```

I can compile the `.cpp`-files to libraries `IntFoo.so` and `FloatFoo.so`.

The implementations will be used in an executable based on `main.cpp`:

```
#include "FooHeader.hpp"
int main()
{
    Foo<float> foo;
    Foo<int> iFoo;
    iFoo.FooFun();
    foo.FooFun();
}
```

When compiling the executable:

```
clang++ main.cpp -L./ -lIntFoo -lFloatFoo
```

How do I know if the compiler actually used the instantiations in `IntFoo,FloatFoo`, or if it instantiated new code implicitly from the initialization in `main.cpp`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448094/can-we-see-the-templates-instantiated-by-the-c-compiler

Comment: You should move definitions into .cpp file so compiler won't be able to instantiate new code.

Comment: You can be pretty sure `main.cpp` instanciates the templates. Without adding `extern template struct Foo<float>; extern template struct Foo<int>;` to `FooHeader.hpp` the compiler just doesn't know that you're expecting the instanciation to be done in some other translation unit...

Answer (score 0):

`extern template struct Foo<>` in `main.cpp` solves this issue, as suggested by @fabian. With the following `main.cpp`:

```
#include "FooHeader.hpp"
extern template struct Foo<float>;
extern template struct Foo<int>;


int main()
{
    Foo<float> foo;
    Foo<int> iFoo;
    iFoo.FooFun();
    foo.FooFun();
}
```

The compiler will throw error if libraries `IntFoo` and `FloatFoo` are not linked.