# What are the pros and cons of learning assembly language?

Tags: assembly

Is there much point to learning assembly language in the modern world or should I just stick with high level languages?

Comment: It's good to understand how compilers and CPUs work, and to understand how to optimise your own code based on that, but you're probably not ever going to be writing assembly directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it worthwile to learn assembly language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623219/is-it-worthwile-to-learn-assembly-language)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pros:

- You will understand computers better
- You will understand languages better
- You will be able to, if required, write some code that really screams, or follows some constraints (e.g. writing stuff on a micro controller). Though usually C is sufficient.

Cons:

- You may become a presumptuous prick because you actually understand computers, and suffering fools is a hard problem.
- You may feel inclined to grow a manly beard and start hacking the Linux kernel or writing device drivers

Comment: @slebetman, I was trying to figure out what cons **learning something new** could possibly have. Those were the only ones I could come up with ;)

Comment: There may be drawbacks if you work under the assumption that learning something new would necessarily evict something else previously learned from the brain. You may, for example, forget how to knit, or ride bicycles..

Comment: @Leeor, if you work under that assumption then you'd learn something new, then, wouldn't you? ;)

Comment: also, writing assembly causes OCD levels to go way up.

Answer (score 2):

I asked myself the same question when learning Assembly Language.

Assembly and understanding how hardware works can be fun and educational. You will lean how compilers, CPUs and memory works. You will learn little tricks that when applied will optimize your code. You might never wright in assembly when you get a job. A good understanding of how the machine works is always good.

I used to translate C code to assembly to optimize it for a class.

Answer (score 0):

The "point" always depends... There are still some companies, that expect you to write in assembly (to provide some fast drivers, some extremely fast graphics, some software features achievable on a specific machine etc.). From a strictly practical point of view, I believe it is quite good to be able to write something in assembly (write a few programs just to learn some general rules) as then when you find yourself in a situation where your job is to write assembly code, you can study further, as you have already had some experience with it (and the beginnings are the worst).

On the other hand, there is not much point in having your mind set only on assembly, as most of the software written today is, ofcourse, high-level (if not super-high-level) programming. So to summarise *my* opinion: yes, it is good to spend some time with assembly code (as assembly languages are generally similar, if you learn to write in one type of assembly it will always be a good base for learning other assembly languages), but it is important to remember to stay open-minded and learn a few languages, as this only increases your skill as a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to high level languages only, there will always come up problems that you will not understand, because their root lies in how the computer actually works. And of course, compilers and lanugages are also just programs and may have bugs, and when you encounter such then you will not be able to understand it and work aorund it.

On the other hand, learning assembly, might hamper your understanding of high level concepts, so it's a good idea if you have a good grasp on both.